# jquery autocomplete no muestra resultados

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc, autocomplete

he revisado varias preguntas de este tema ya y con ninguna he podido resolver el problema.
estoy tratando de utilizar el autocomplete de jquery pero no me muestra niguna sugerencia, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando en la vista

```
$(function () {
            $("#txtAutor").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("ListarPrueba", "Periodismo")",
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { fragmento: request.term },
                        success: function (resultado) {
                            console.log(resultado);
                            response($.map(resultado, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.name, value: item.name };
                            }))
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            alert(resultado);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

en el controlador tengo esta fucion

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ListarPrueba(string fragmento)
    {
        fragmento = Request.QueryString["term"];
        List<Autor> lista = new List<Autor>();
        lista = new CN_Autores().ListarPrueba(fragmento);
        return Json(new { resultado = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

la funcion ListarPrueba en la clase CN_Autores es esta

```
 public List<Autor> ListarPrueba(string fragmento)
    {
        return objCapaDatos.ListarPrueba(fragmento);
    }
```

y la funcion listar en la clase CD_Autores es esta

```
 public List<Autor> ListarPrueba(string fragmento)
    {
        List<Autor> lista = new List<Autor>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cxn))
            {
                string query = "select id, name from authors where name like '%" + fragmento + "%'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oconexion.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        lista.Add(new Autor()
                        {
                            id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
                            name = dr["name"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string mensaje = ex.Message;
            lista = new List<Autor>();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

decir que en la vista estoy usando un console.log() para ver si el metodo del controller me devuelve resultados y si me devuelve resultados, solo que no se muestran como sugerencias al escribir en el input. cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: que te muestra `console.log()`?

Comment: @alanfcm el console.log() me muestra el array con los resultados que se deberian mostrar, o sea que la respuesta del controller esta llegando a la vista lo que no se muestran

Answer (score 0):

He replicado tu problema y he visto lo siguiente:

1. Tu código no devuelve errores a la primera, si el json es devuelto en la forma correcta, que podria ser así, por ejemplo:

```
[{"name":"Pedro"},{"name":"Juan"}]
```

Como no has puesto ningún ejemplo del mismo pero afirmabas que devolvia un array, dábamos por supuesto que era correcto, pero seguramente no lo es. Debes revisar bien lo que devuelve y en caso de dudas ponlo en la pregunta tal como te habian sugerido en los comentarios.

2. Tu código, aunque se ejecuta sin errores, siempre va a mostrar todas las opciones, pues no filtra como se espera al utilizar el autocomplete.
3. Tu código no está optimizado, y por cada tecleo lanza una petición **ajax**, lo cual puede saturar al servidor, pues para buscar Juan lanza 4 peticiones, y siempre devuelve todas las opciones.
4. Tal como te he sugerido en los comentarios, la solución pasaba por modificar la petición ajax haciéndola similar al ejemplo que aparece en este enlace: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#xml (pulsando en la última pestaña donde pone **XML data parsed one**) para hacerlo usando **ajax()**.  Yo lo he hecho y comprobado y así me funciona bien, con una sola petición ajax() escriba lo que escriba, pues me carga bien los datos en el automplete a la primera y no por cada carácter entrado en el input:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("ListarPrueba", "Periodismo")",
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function( resultado ) {
        console.log(resultado);
        var data = resultado.map(function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.name, value: item.name
          };
        });

        $("#txtAutor").autocomplete({
          source: data
        });
      }
    });
```

Si te vuelve a dar el error **resultado.map is not a function**, por favor agrega a tu pregunta un extracto exacto (o completo) del array que te devuelve para estar seguros que parte del problema no está allí, como te he dicho antes.

Comment: cuando pruebo ese cambio me arrobja un error que dice lo siguiente.....Index:599 Uncaught TypeError: resultado.map is not a function

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta... a ver si ahora te funciona

Comment: No, no creo que funcione... lo siento, voy a borrar esta respuesta, no he recreado tu escenario y pensaba que lo tenia, pero ahora veo que no... deberias basarte más en la ultima pestaña de esta página: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#xml para hacerlo usando ajax (donde pone **XML data parsed one**)

Comment: tendre que seguir buscando pq la sugerencia que me ofreces sigue sin mostrar ninguna sugerencia. Gracias

Comment: @Hans Revisa la última actualización de mi respuesta a ver si te sirve